# ios - don't understand how to properly work with arrays when dynamically populating lists

Tags: ios, ios5, nsmutablearray

I am trying to figure out how to create a list of strings that populates a UITableView and makes sure that each cell has proper size to fit each string (some of the strings can get quite long)

What I am trying to do is declare a tempArray to hold the list of items as I am populating the array.

In my .h file, I declare it like this:

```
@interface BusinessTopicController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
 ....

@end

NSMutableArray *newArray;
```

but in the .m file when I try to do this:

```
@implementation BusinessTopicController
@synthesize newArray;
```

I get this syntax error:

Property implementation must have its declaration in the @interface

But when I add this to the @interface

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *newArray;
```

and then it gave me a different error on the @synthesize newArray; line which is this:

```
Property's synthesized getter follows cocoa naming convention for returning 'owned' objects
```

I googled this issue and the solutions seem to be overkill because it seems to me I am just making some dumb mistake somewhere.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "*Property's synthesized getter follows cocoa naming convention*..." compiler error is generated because your property begins with `new` which means the synthesized getter method begins with `new`, and that is reserved for methods which return a +1 retained object. So try and find another name for the property.

With the most recent version of Xcode and the clang compiler, you just need a `@property` declaration in the interface. You can even skip the `@synthesize` and an underscore-prefixed ivar will be synthesized for you. Delete the `NSMutableArray *newArray;` line entirely because that's sitting outside the interface and is essentially a global variable.

If you want to keep the property private, you can also declare it in an anonymous category/class extension in your .m file like this:

```
// At the top of BusinessTopicController.m
@interface BusinessTopicController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *theArray;

@end
```

Comment: thank you. So the main issue was that I started the variable with the "new" string? Thank you, it fixed the compilation problem. I will accept in a few min when SO allows me to do that.